# Edgecast RTMP stream URLs

Tags: rtmp, amazon-cloudfront, edgecast

Edgecast RTMP URLs are as follows:

```
rtmp://abc.edgecast.com/a_folder/b_folder/mp4:astream.mp4
```

Cloudfront though mandates it as follows:

```
rtmp://abc.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:a_folder/b_folder/a_stream.mp4
```

mp4 should precede the user folder structure.

Is this CDN specific? Can edgecast do:

```
rtmp://abc.edgecast.com/mp4:a_folder/b_folder/astream.mp4
```

Comment: I think I have asked a similar question before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981674/why-rtmp-streaming-protocals-url-path-different-from-each-other, from which you may get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

No, media identifier should before the stream/file name. The first one is correct.
To my knowledge, it is not CDN specific, that's how the player(s) expect them.

Comment: No, Cloudfront only works if the url is specified like the second case. It needs media_identifier before the user folders. RTMP has a NET connection URL and stream name. Stream name should be preceeded by the media identifier. My question is can stream name have directory hierarchy? Is this CDN specific or handled at player level?