# How to sign an RTMP url for Amazon CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, rtmp

I'm trying to create signed urls for an RTMP distribution in Amazon's CloudFront. I have the following working:

- Signed URLs for Web distribution (over `http` and `https`) - so I know I am able to sign URLs correctly.
- Unsigned URLs for RTMP distribution - so I know I have CloudFront and S3 setup properly for RTMP.

**Main question -** now that I'm trying to get a **signed** url for RTMP, it never seems to be playable.

Part of the confusion is based on the format of the url (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981674/why-rtmp-streaming-protocals-url-path-different-from-each-other)). So I don't know if it matters which part of the url I sign - if I sign the whole thing (like my http urls), or if I only sign a portion, and if I include the `mp4:` prefix in the path.

There seem to be a lot of pseudo-similar questions on Stackoverflow, but they seem to be related to slightly different issues, and not about actually creating a signed url for RTMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are many variations to how a RTMP url can be created, which 
caused a large portion of the confusion. The following is the way that I was able to get this to work with Amazon CloudFront. To be clear, this was to be used in a `*.SMIL` file, so it might be different if you only need a single url.

1. The `S3ObjectSummary` object has a `key` for the file, which might be something like `folder1/folder2/video.mp4`.
2. Use the above key, and remove the `.mp4` extension.
3. Sign the url as normal (I used `CloudFrontService.signUrlCanned()`.
4. In the `*.smil` file that is generated, set the `base` reference to `rtmp://<CloudFront RTMP Distribution Domain>/cfx/st`
5. In the `video` element, set the `height` and `width`, and in the `src` attribute, prepend `mp4:` to the signed url portion.

Here is an example SMIL file.

```
<smil data-livestyle-extension="available">
    <head>
        <meta base="rtmp://some-cloud-front-domain.net/cfx/st"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <switch>
            <video height="720" width="1280" src="mp4:<signed portion of video path>" />
            <video height="480" width="853" src="mp4:<signed portion of video path>" />
        </switch>
    </body>
</smil>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python/boto3, I've managed to sign media files with the rsa_signer

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#generate-a-signed-url-for-amazon-cloudfront

by signing only the path to the media file.

Let's say you want to stream an S3 bucket media file located at 'videos/test.mp4'
Following the boto3 example from the link above, here's what you can do to serve the file with flowplayer:

```
signed_url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(
    'videos/test.mp4', date_less_than=expire_date)
```

Then in the flowplayer code (Django template syntax):

```
<div class="flowplayer fp-slim" data-rtmp="rtmp://{{cloudfront_domain_prefix}}.cloudfront.net:1935/cfx/st">
   <video>
     <source type="video/flash" src="mp4:{{signed_src}}">
   </video>
</div>
```